# Cloning into a bare repository gives remotes

Tags: git

Just a minor question. I'm following the book "Version control with Git" (O'Reilly's book)
and I just have done a

```
git clone --bare ... ...
```

Now, the book shows that the new bare repository doesn't contains any remotes.
Anyway, I did this same operation with one of my Git's repos but I do find remotes
after performing the git clone --bare operation:

```
$ cat config
...
[remote "origin"]
url = /home/jivifair/RMT_networks/
```

Is this because perhaps of the Git version that I have? Should I be aware of different behaviour since the bare repository knows where it come from?

Comment: Where does the book show that the repo doesn't contain any remotes? Can you quote the relevant passage?

Answer (score 0):

According to you,

> the book shows that the new bare repository doesn't contains any remotes.

Did the book use `git init --bare` instead of `git clone --bare`? The difference is important. `git clone` is basically a `git init` followed by a `git fetch`...from a remote. It doesn't make sense to clone a repository B from another repository A, without setting up A as a remote for B, because otherwise how would you do the `git fetch` without a remote?

Comment: It uses `git clone --bare`. Maybe is an errata or code cut at the book. But I wanted to ask anyway because in the text is stressed that a bare-authorative repository does not know whose are their "children"

Comment: @user2820579 right, that makes sense, a clone doesn't know about child clones (unless you add them as additional remotes), but it would know about ***its parent***, the repo that it was cloned from...which page of the book is this from? Which edition of the book?

Comment: The book is Version Control with Git, by Jon Loeliger and Matthew McCullough, Ed. O'Reilly, 2nd edition, pages 205, 206